# решение задачи на C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
namespace std{
int A, B;
int main(){
    cin >> A >> B >> endl;
    cout << A * B;
    return 0;
}
}
```

я только начал писать на С++, можете сказать в чем ошибка

Comment: Используйте литературу - например для начала почитайте Страуструпа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int A, B;
    cin >> A >> B;
    cout << A * B;
    return 0;
}
```

Исправил ваш код.
Ошибки можете найти при сравнении.

Comment: Исправить то исправили, но лучше бы обьяснили что к чему.    Что  std::endl  является манипулятором только для вывода(результат  выражения это std:::ostream&)

Answer (score 0):

1.Напишите `Using namespace std;`
2.уберите `>>endl` из поля `cin`

Comment: Проблема может еще быть в используемых вами версиях, какую версию studio используете? ( Какого года) ?

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Comment: не обязательно  (даже не желательно)  использовать все пространство std. Достаточно using std::cin; using std::cout; (не Using)

Comment: А лучше везде указывать std без using. using хорош на типах с длинными именами

Answer (score -1):

Смотри, напиши using namespace std;
Введи ещё одну переменную, например C
И вот ещё, пиши C=A*B;
Должно работать

Comment: Забыл, ну и для конца, выведи C на экран